# Laravel dynamic query with multiple where conditions

Tags: laravel

The following query built with Laravel doesn't work (it does not return any records):

```
   $this->projectstages = ProjectBuildStage::leftJoin('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_build_stages.project_id')
        ->leftJoin('build_stages as bs', 'bs.id', '=', 'project_build_stages.build_stage_id')
        ->leftJoin('build_stage_types as bst', 'bst.build_stage_id', '=', 'bs.id')
        ->select('bs.build_stage', 'bst.build_stage_type', 'bst.id as build_stage_type_id', 'bs.id')
        ->where('projects.id', $ProjectId)
        ->where('bst.project_id',$ProjectId);

    if ($buildstageId != 0 && $buildstageId !=  null && $buildstageId !=  'all') {
        $this->projectstages->where('bs.id', '=', $buildstageId);
    }

    $this->projectstages->orderBy('bs.sort_order', 'asc')->orderBy('bst.sort_order', 'asc');
    $this->projectstages->get();
```

ToSQL result:

```
"select `bs`.`build_stage`, `bst`.`build_stage_type`, `bst`.`id` as `build_stage_type_id`, `bs`.`id` from `project_build_stages` left join `projects` on `projects`.`id` = `project_build_stages`.`project_id` left join `build_stages` as `bs` on `bs`.`id` = `project_build_stages`.`build_stage_id` left join `build_stage_types` as `bst` on `bst`.`build_stage_id` = `bs`.`id` where `projects`.`id` = ? and `bst`.`project_id` = ? and `bs`.`id` = ? and `project_build_stages`.`company_id` = ? order by `bs`.`sort_order` asc, `bst`.`sort_order` asc ◀"
```

But, if I remove the **if** and I make the query into a single statement it will work:

```
  $this->projectstages = ProjectBuildStage::leftJoin('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_build_stages.project_id')
        ->leftJoin('build_stages as bs', 'bs.id', '=', 'project_build_stages.build_stage_id')
        ->leftJoin('build_stage_types as bst', 'bst.build_stage_id', '=', 'bs.id')
        ->select('bs.build_stage', 'bst.build_stage_type', 'bst.id as build_stage_type_id', 'bs.id')
        ->where('projects.id', $ProjectId)
        ->where('bst.project_id',$ProjectId)
        ->orderBy('bs.sort_order', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('bst.sort_order', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

ToSQL result:

```
"select `bs`.`build_stage`, `bst`.`build_stage_type`, `bst`.`id` as `build_stage_type_id`, `bs`.`id` from `project_build_stages` left join `projects` on `projects`.`id` = `project_build_stages`.`project_id` left join `build_stages` as `bs` on `bs`.`id` = `project_build_stages`.`build_stage_id` left join `build_stage_types` as `bst` on `bst`.`build_stage_id` = `bs`.`id` where `projects`.`id` = ? and `bst`.`project_id` = ? and `bs`.`id` = ? and `project_build_stages`.`company_id` = ? order by `bs`.`sort_order` asc, `bst`.`sort_order` asc ◀"
```

Could anyone point me what I am doing wrong in the first example? The second one works just fine but the first one doesn't return any record

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of  $buildstageId when you run that and do you have that record in the db?

Comment: Yes, it's 8 in the specific case and yes it is in the database. Even if I change the $buildstageId or even if I completely remove the if, the query will not return any record

Comment: instead of calling get() you can call dd($this->projectstages->toSql()); on both queries and post the result to see if they are different

Comment: updated the question with the toSQL results

Comment: there is something wrong with sql results. second sql does not match with query. There are no bs.id condition in second query.

Comment: Also your queries just fine. I think there no existing record in your database which provides first query conditions including bs.id

Comment: I tested the query in mysql and it returns records. It's just that it doesn't work in the first example..